# How to create datepicker with input field in html or ftl

Tags: html, frontend, freemarker

I am learning html and ftl these days.
Currently, I want to create input field with icon for datepicker.
Something like this:

[image]

Hope you will share some ideas with me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This one will help:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="demoForm" action="success.html" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row col-6">
                <label class="col-auto col-form-label">Select Date: </label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" />
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```